# Understanding basic use of moment for date checking

Tags: time, momentjs, utc

Please I am new to using `moments`, and don't fully understand how `utc` and `isBefore` methods work.

I have the below code which returns `false`, I need help understanding why even though logically it should be true since `2021-07-11` is before `2021-07-12`

```
var moment = require('moment');

moment.utc('2021-07-11').isBefore('2021-07-12', 'day') // returns false
```

Any pointer to resource or why false is returned would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your local timezone

Comment: @Chris Schaller, it's GMT + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your local timezone?

You are comparing local 12th, to UTC 11. If your timezone is in the *western* hemisphere, then this is the expected result due to the `'day'` parameter. When a timezone is not specified, momentJS will assume the local timezone.

The whole point of *momentjs* is to take timezones out of the equation for comparisons, so `.isBefore()` will return `true` *only* when the day component of the value passed in is *less than* the starting value when both values are transposed to the same timezone.

In this case, the day component of your two dates is *equal* and there before before will return false.

If your local timezone is UTC +2, then we can break your code down like this:

```
var utc = moment.utc('2021-07-11'):
var local = moment('2021-07-12');
// Local in UTC : 2021-07-11T22:00:00Z
utc.isBefore(local, 'day') // False
utc.isEqual(local, 'day') // True
```